# Delete dynamically a list with divs.Only JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When I check ALL the checkboxes and press the button always there is a last node that remains.
I know it is because of the `parentNode` and because the index at the DOM tree is still in the memory or something like this.
If somebody can help me to understand what to do, I would appreciate it.

```js
function deleteChecked() {
    var node_listFields = document.getElementsByClassName('fields');
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("check");
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            node_listFields[i].parentNode.removeChild(node_listFields[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteChecked()" />
<div class="fields">
    <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Θέρμανση
    <input type="text" />

<br></br></div>
<div class="fields">
    <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Διάφορα
    <input type="text" />

<br></br></div>
<div class="fields">
    <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Διάφορα Yλικά
    <input type="text" />

<br></br></div>
<hr/>
```

?

Comment: have you tried to register the onchange event on the checkboxes? Maybe this could help you...

Comment: You appear to be getting a list of checkboxes and then attempting to modify a different list altogether? I see errors such as " Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." because you're accessing the body when you hit the `parentNode` of the `fields` class? Second's answer is correct otherwise though.

Comment: can you explain this  simply ? ...I am a student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it using regressive iteration.

As for my understanding, the DOM nodes index always have to be fixed: 0,1,2,3...:

---

Progressive iteration `(i=0; i<3; i++){`

- **i = 0** :

  - **`checkbox[0]`** is removed;
  - **`checkbox[1]`** become new **`checkbox[0]`** as DOM nodes index always starts with **`0`**;
- **i = 1** :

  - **`checkbox[1]`** is removed, **`checkbox[0]`** stays in DOM (1 node skipped);
  - **`checkbox[2]`** become new **`checkbox[1]`**;
- **i = 2** :

  - **`checkbox[2]`** is removed, **`checkbox[0]`** & **`[1]`** stays in DOM (2 nodes skipped);
  - **`node[3]`** become new **`node[2]`**;
- Finish loop `};`

2 skipped checkboxes. Need to repeat the loop until there's less than 2 boxes left, because the every other box will be skipped each time.

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i<inputElems.length; i++){
    if(inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked === true) {
        inputElems[i].parentNode.remove();
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/kzqojafb/)**

---

Regressive iteration `(i=2; i>=0; i--){`

- **i = 2** :

  - **`checkbox[2]`** is removed (the last checkbox in index);
  - **`node[3]`**(not checkbox) become new **`node[2]`**;
- **i = 1** :

  - **`checkbox[1]`** is removed, (the last checkbox in updated index);
  - **`node[2]`**(not checkbox) become new **`node[1]`**;
- **i = 0** :

  - **`checkbox[0]`** is removed, (the last checkbox in updated index);
  - **`node[1]`**(not checkbox) become new **`node[0]`**(no more checkboxes!);
- Finish loop `};`

Skipped checkboxes: 0.

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = inputElems.length-1; i>= 0; i--){
    if(inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked === true) {
        inputElems[i].parentNode.remove();
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/onhkdw27/)**

---

Comment: this is very clever! i give tick for this reason :)

Comment: why does this happening ?

Comment: hah ok i get  it is static because you use the Tag no the ClassName...no clever but still elegant

Comment: Yes. I filtered the DOM by tag name and type. As for the class names, @ **Second Rikudo** explained why it happens. But even filtering by tag and type with `i++` will cause problems : http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/kzqojafb/

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `HTMLCollection` object returned by `getElementsByClassName` is live, meaning that when you remove a node in it, it's automatically updated (And so, your `i` now points to a wrong item), that is causing an error after one deletion, which is why only one item is ever deleted.

The correct approach would be to convert into an array (or use `document.querySelectorAll()`, which returns a non-live list)

```js
function deleteChecked() {
  var node_listFields = document.getElementsByClassName('fields');
  // This converts to an array.
  var nodeArray = [].slice.call(node_listFields);

  var onlyCheckedArray = nodeArray.filter(function findIfCheckboxIsChecked(node) {
    // Returns if the checkbox inside this node is checked.
    return node.querySelector('.check').checked;
  })

  // Here onlyCheckedArray is an array with nodes with only checked checkboxes.
  // So let's remove them all!

  onlyCheckedArray.forEach(function removeNode(node) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="deleteChecked()" />
<div class="fields">
  <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Θέρμανση
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="fields">
  <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Διάφορα
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="fields">
  <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Διάφορα Yλικά
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<br></br>
<hr/>
```

And on **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp1478x5/16/)**

Comment: or decreasing i every time you delete.

Comment: @null Yes, that would work. But I find that instructing an iteration over an array is far more readable than instructing a *backwards* iteration over a numeric variable, which happens to have calls to an array inside. :)